# PHP json encode not properly decoding in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, decode, encode

So I have an issue where data that's encoded using php is not decoding properly in javascript. Here is the error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmLXL.jpg)

The JSON looks fine but javascript is throwing an error and I have no idea why.

Here is my code:

JS:

```
function requestData( url )
{
document.getElementById( "spinner" ).style.visibility = "visible";

var xhttp;
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest( );
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function( ) {
    if ( this.readyState == 4 ) {
        if( this.status == 200 )
        {
            document.getElementById( "spinner" ).style.visibility = "hidden";

            console.log( this.responseText );

            return this.responseText;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById( "spinner" ).style.visibility = "hidden";

            document.getElementById( "errorsec" ).innerHTML = ":( An unknown error has happened and your request was canceled. Code: " + this.status;

            return false;  
        }
    }
};
xhttp.open( "GET", url, true );
xhttp.send( );   
}

function handleSignup( )
{
var username = document.getElementById( "un" ).value; // Get text field values
var password = document.getElementById( "pw" ).value;

var requestObject = requestData( "../../FRAMEWORK/createaccount.php?name=" + username + "&password=" + password, false );

var returnObject;

if( requestObject != false )
{
    requestObject = JSON.parse( requestObject );

    console.log( returnObject.value );
}
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
# REV 1.0.0

$name = $_GET[ "name" ]; # Get values to set
$password = $_GET[ "password" ];

$file = fopen( "../USER_STORE/userindex.json", "r" ); # Load user index
$accounts = json_decode( fread($file, filesize( "../USER_STORE/userindex.json" ) ), true );
fclose($file);

$alreadyExists = false; # Check to see if username already is in use
foreach($accounts as $val) {
if( $val == $name )
{
    $alreadyExists = true;
}
}

if( !$alreadyExists ) # If username is not in use
{
$UUID = sizeof( $accounts ) + 1;

$toAppend = array( "username" => $name, "password" => hash( "sha256", $password ) ); # Create append list

mkdir( "../USER_STORE/" . $UUID ); # Append user data
$file = fopen( "../USER_STORE/" . $UUID . "/accountinfo.json", "w" );
fwrite( $file, json_encode( $toAppend ) );
fclose( $file );

$accounts[ $UUID ] = $name; # Create new user index

$file = fopen( "../USER_STORE/userindex.json", "w" ); # Update userindex
fwrite( $file, json_encode( $accounts ) );
fclose( $file );

$return = array( "value" => "created" ); # Return message
echo( json_encode( $return ) );
}
else # Account is in use
{
$return = array( "value" => "account_in_use" ); # Return error message
echo( json_encode( $return ) );
}
?>
```

Comment: Mayhaps you have a space happening somewhere or some invisible characters, possibly before the `<?php` at the top of the page?

Comment: What does the requestObject look like before trying JSON.parse()?

Comment: Here is what it looks like before:{"returnValue":"account_in_use"}

Comment: There don't seem to be any extra spaces

Comment: JSON is NOT A DATABASE!!!

Comment: You don't understand what I'm doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` works asynchronously. So your function `requestData` ends after the `xhttp.send();` and does not return anything. The event handler for `readystatechange` (which is called a bit later, once `XMLHttpRequest` actually receives the response from the server) does return a value, but nothing is done with it.

Solution: move parsing and interpretation of the response in that event handler.

Additional notes:

1. When you build an URL, you need to escape (using `encodeURIComponent`) the parameters. What do you think will happen if any of the two fields contains spaces, or special characters such as `%` or `&`?
2. When you hash a password, you have to salt it first. Or use a ready-made function such as `password_hash` which will do it for you.
3. You may want to use `file_get_contents` / `file_put_contents` to read/write your user file, that will simplify your code quite a bit. Or better yet, a database.

Comment: Hi, so I re did my code, but I'm still having the same issue. Here is the new code: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Ycx5AQmw)

Comment: Use a snippet or jsFiddle for code, it allows direct testing. Quick check reveals a typo: `callback( true, this.resoponseText );`. There may be more errors.

Comment: The typo was actually in the ide https://gyazo.com/eed189f0dd5270c53c671b1f1165f817 Nice catch!